# How to write the php code to echo the json object and xml object?

Tags: xml, json, echo

```
var person='{
   "First_Name":"Paulwin",
   "Last_Name":"Martin",
   "Address":[
      {
         "Door_No":"1661/A1",
         "Street":"Rose Nagar",
         "City":"Sivagangai"
      }
   ],
   "Phone":[
      {
         "Mobile":"+9174188784",
         "Land_Line":"04575244555",
         "Skype":"7418874384"

      }
   ]
}';
```

this is my json objects and please tell me how to echo mobile number using php??

Answer (score 0):

$objPerson = json_decode($Person);
print $objPerson->{'Phone'}->{'Mobile'};